# force .htaccess creation file with some default rules

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

i have a question about a possible configuration on server, when i install some php scripts or cms, they create .htaccess file into folder destination, with some own rules; my server is configured to have ( for example ) Options +SymLinkIfOwnerMatch, but if in the .htaccess file that was created there's default Options +Followsymlinks, application reports 500 internal server error.

Could be a configuration to force that every new .htaccess file have to have some rules and not other?

thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `AllowOverride` in you server configuration you can define which options can be configured in `.htaccess` and which not.